# Detect roaming on CDMA phones in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In my app, I wanted to detect if phone is in roaming or not. I see that there is API in TelephonyManager

```
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telManager.isNetworkRoaming();
```

But the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#isNetworkRoaming%28%29 says " For GSM purpose". Does this mean this API will fail on CDMA network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RoamingListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony =
            (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephony.isNetworkRoaming())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Is on TelephonyM Roaming", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just worried about the comment 'GSM puposes' in documetation

Comment: i didin't tested it in cdma  phones try it